# Copy rows from multiple sheets into one sheet

Tags: vba, excel

```
Public Sub SubName()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim iCounter As Long
Dim wso As Worksheet
Dim rw As Long
Dim lastrow As Long

Set wso = Sheets("Master")

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If ws.Name Like "*" & "danger" & "*" Then
    ws.Select
    lastrow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row
            For iCounter = 2 To lastrow
                If ws.Cells(iCounter, 8) < 0.15 And ws.Cells(iCounter, 8) > -0.1 Then

                    ws.Cells(iCounter, 8).EntireRow.Copy

                    rw = wso.Cells(wso.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
                    wso.Cells(rw, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll

                End If
            Next iCounter

    End If
Next ws
End Sub
```

This is what the code does:

1. Look through all sheets, find sheets with text "danger"
2. With sheets named "danger*", go through column H and copy the entire row if criteria is met
3. Paste the entire row onto master sheet

I believe the code is working fine up to the point where I need it to paste onto the master sheet. The problem i'm getting is that it simply pastes over the same row on the master sheet, instead of going row+1.

The end result is there's only one row showing on the master sheet and it's the last row in the iteration that's to be pasted.

Any help is appreciated!

[image]

Comment: `instead of going row+1.` so you know what you need to do XD Edit: oh, `rw` is already `+1` hmmm

Comment: i dunno where to put it :(

Comment: Don't think it makes a difference as it resolves the string first but `If ws.Name Like "*" & "danger" & "*" Then` can just be `If ws.Name Like "*danger*" Then`.

Comment: @nbayly - wrong thread :P

Comment: in the data that is being copied, is there data in column A?

Comment: @ScottCraner, i'm a fool................ that fixed it. thanks so much!

Comment: why don't you just try with `rw = rw +1` ?

Comment: i'm a novice at VBA, thanks for the tip!!

Comment: Do not fret much, I did roughly the same thing just a few weeks ago.  It helps to go line by line and speak out loud in detail what each line does as if to someone that does not know programming.

Comment: @ScottCraner, we should all have [rubber duckys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging).

Answer (score 0):

Try this to copy rows from one worksheet to another worksheet(with each row on different row):

```
Dim i, lastRow as Integer

Dim wso, ws, copyFrom as Worksheet

Set wso = Sheets("Master")

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

If ws.Name Like "*" & "danger" & "*" Then

    copyFrom =  ws.Select

End if


lastRow = Sheets(copyFrom).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For i=1 to lastRow

If <--your criteria--> then

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(copyFrom).Rows(i).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(wso).Rows(i)

End if

Next i
Next ws
```